# Chrome Extension Notification Buttons not showing on MacOs/OSX

Tags: macos, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, notifications

I'm currently working on a Chrome Extension using the Notification Api. On Chrome in Windows and Linux its working ok, but in MacOs / OSX the notification is being shown without the button. I tried to look any information in [Chrome Notification API](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/notifications) but they doesn't say anything about buttons not working for MacOS users like for other functionality as imageURL or appIconMaskUrl.

This is the declaration of my notification on the extension:

```
        type: "basic",
        title: message.participant + " has arrived!",
        message: message.description,
        iconUrl: "icon.jpg",
        buttons: [{title:'Go to Project'}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, from the [recent update](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/native-mac-os-notifications), the action button icons will not be used and the user will need to hover over the notification and select the "More" button to see the available actions.

From this [GitHub post](https://github.com/julienXX/terminal-notifier),

> To enable actions on the notification (the buttons that allow the user to select an option), open **System Preferences** > **Notifications**, select **terminal-notifer** in the sidebar, and select the "**Alerts**" alert style.

Comment: Yes, i was recently informed about the more button on the extension. Thanks for your answer.